# No root node detected when loading XML in IE using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to parse a XML file using Javascript and I'm running into issues on IE7.

If I have this code:

```
function LoadXml()
{
    var xmlPath = document.getElementById("hsTreeviewXmlPath").value;

    var xmlhttp=false;
    /*@cc_on @*/
    /*@if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
    // JScript gives us Conditional compilation, we can cope with old IE versions.
    // and security blocked creation of the objects.
     try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      alert("here1");
     } catch (e) {
      try {
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       alert("here2");
      } catch (E) {
       xmlhttp = false;
      }
     }
    @end @*/
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            alert("here3");
        } catch (e) {
            xmlhttp=false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && window.createRequest) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = window.createRequest();
            alert("here4");
        } catch (e) {
            xmlhttp=false;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET",xmlPath,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    ParseXml(xmlDoc);
}

function ParseXml(xmlDoc)
{
    var root = xmlDoc.documentElement;
    alert(root);

    for(i=0; i< root.childNodes.length; i++)
    {
        var node = root.childNodes[i];
        if(node.nodeType ==1) //process element nodes (type 1)
        {
            if(node.childNodes.length > 1)
            {
                CreateChildren("hsTreeview",node);
            }
            else
            {
                AddNode("hsTreeview", node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In FF and Chrome this works correctly, adding nodes as it should, but on IE7 I get a scripting error and the specific error:

> Object required

This gives a line number relating to the line:

```
for(i=0; i< root.childNodes.length; i++)
{
```

The alert box tells me that in IE, the root node, which is being populated from `xmlDoc.documentElement` is null.

I have confirmed, using the alerts here1 etc that in IE7 it is using the `xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");` object.

Is there some way to fix this up as it's really frustrating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the XML file is served with the proper text/xml Mime Type.

**Edit Bellow:**

Also make sure that the XML file is served through an *http* server from the same *domain* and *port* as the web page. IE will prevent a web page from accessing URLs outside their originating domain or files on your local computer for security reasons.

Comment: and how does one do that? This is just a file sitting on a Sharepoint directory. In my test case (off the HDD), it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Alastair Is it possible to rename the file in `var xmlPath` with an .xml extension and load the web page through http?

Comment: the file is designated an XML file, the path ends in ".xml". What exactly do you mean by load through http?

Comment: @Alastair Open the web page using an http URL as opposed to loading it from the local file system (which I assume you mean by "off the HDD"). Also try loading the .xml file through an http URL. It should get syntax coloring in ie if it's recognized as XML

Comment: indeed this seems to have worked. Weird. Do you have an explanation why? Now to work out why the child elements aren't being shown.